# Three JS re-using an Imported objects geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am importing an object that is used several times in my program. Since I dont want to have uneccesary geometries in memory I would like to re-use the geometry. I have attempted to write a loader like so:

```
var tmpGeo = geometries[ID];
if (!tmpGeo) {
    tmpGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometries[ID] = tmpGeo;
    objLoader.load("/models/" + ID + ".obj", function (mesh) {
        tmpGeo = mesh.children[0].geometry;
    });
}
obj.add(new THREE.Mesh(tmpGeo, tmpMat));
```

This way it should re use the geometry of the imported object for multiple Three JS objects. However this doesn't seem to work or update the geometry once loaded.

Essentially I would like to know if it is possible to import an object only once and reusing it without storing a new geomtry in memory each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the model loads asynchronously, and you're creating the mesh without waiting for the model to load. Overwriting the `tmpGeo` variable doesn't update the mesh, which still points to the empty BufferGeometry. You need to do something like this, instead:

```
var tmpGeo = geometries[ID];
if (!tmpGeo) {
  tmpGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  geometries[ID] = tmpGeo;
  objLoader.load("/models/" + ID + ".obj", function (mesh) {
      // Update the existing BufferGeometry with loaded data.
      tmpGeo.copy( mesh.children[0].geometry );
  });
}
obj.add(new THREE.Mesh(tmpGeo, tmpMat));
```

Or, you could wait to create the mesh until the geometry has loaded.